# How to store big files in sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

I am working on a project where I have to download files from server and store it in sqlite. It is working fine. I am using BLOB datatype in sqlite to store. But I found there is limitation in BLOB for large files like 400MB or 500MB.[see limits of sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

Also I thought to store the data in a file in physical location in system and store the path in sqlite. But there is chance of user to delete the file accidentally.

How to store such a big file in SQLite.

Comment: SQLLite is not intended to store such large amount of data. You could split the file into smaller parts but you would also lose the advantages of using an ACID database to store them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQLite we can't store such a large volume of data. This is limitation in SQLite.